# How to automatically generate new CSV file according to current time using C++

Tags: c++, csv, clock

I have finished the task of reading sensor data and store into CSV file successfully. But everytime I want to stop reading & storing sensor data, I must close the exe file. Due to the factory operation, they want to continuously run the program during a month without closing the exe file. I was required to modify the code to generate a new CSV file after a period (e.g. 1 hour). So the file name maybe: 20190516_10h0m0s, 20190516_11h0m0s, 20190516_12h0m0s...

I tried to use `(struct tm)` and `for(;timeinfo->tm_min < 60;)` to make a new CSV produced after 60'. But every loop, the item Data, time, Channel are written to the CSV again. It looks weird. But when I create the file dest and put the dest.open outside for loop, it only store correct data format without creating a new CSV as I want. Please suggest me how to make it work as expectation.

```
void EX_GetMultiValue(LONG i_lDriverHandle,
                      WORD i_wSlotID,
                      struct SlotInfo &i_SlotInfo)
{
    char filename[20], filename2[20];
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    timeinfo->tm_mon++; // Because the range of tm_mon is 0~11, so we need to increment it by 1
    timeinfo->tm_year = timeinfo->tm_year + 1900; // Because year counted since 1900

    clock_t start = clock();
    sprintf(filename,
            "%04d%02d%02d_%02dh%02dm%02ds.csv",
            timeinfo->tm_year,
            timeinfo->tm_mon,
            timeinfo->tm_mday,
            timeinfo->tm_hour,
            timeinfo->tm_min,
            timeinfo->tm_sec);
    printf("\nFilename: %s", filename);

    ofstream dest2;
    dest2.open(filename, ios_base::app | ios_base::out);
    dest2 << "Date" << "," << "Time" << "," << "milisecond" << ","
            << "Channel 0" << "," << "Channel 1" << "," << "Channel 2" << ","
            << "Channel 3" << "," << "Channel 4" << "," << "Channel 5" << ","
            << "Channel 6" << "," << "Channel 7" << "," << "Channel 8" << ","
            << "Channel 9" << "," << "Channel 10" << "," << "Channel 11" << ","
            << endl;

    for (; timeinfo->tm_min < 60;)
    {

        ofstream dest;
        dest.open(filename, ios_base::app | ios_base::out);

        LONG lGetMultiValueResult = AIO_GetValues(i_lDriverHandle,
                                                  i_wSlotID,
                                                  wRawValue); //get raw value
        if (ERR_SUCCESS == lGetMultiValueResult)
        {
            clock_t timeElapsed = clock() - start;
            unsigned secElapsed = timeElapsed / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            unsigned msElapsed = timeElapsed / CLOCKS_PER_MS;

            while (msElapsed >= 1000)
                msElapsed -= 1000;
            while ((timeinfo->tm_sec + secElapsed) > 59)
            {
                timeinfo->tm_sec -= 60;
                timeinfo->tm_min++;
            }
            while (timeinfo->tm_min > 59)
            {
                timeinfo->tm_min -= 60;
                timeinfo->tm_hour++;
            }
            while (timeinfo->tm_hour > 23)
            {
                timeinfo->tm_hour -= 24;
                timeinfo->tm_mday++;
            }

            dest << timeinfo->tm_year << "-" << timeinfo->tm_mon << "-"
                    << timeinfo->tm_mday << "," << timeinfo->tm_hour << "h"
                    << timeinfo->tm_min << "m" << timeinfo->tm_sec + secElapsed
                    << "s" << ",";
            dest << msElapsed << "ms" << ",";
            for (iCnt = 0; iCnt < g_ChannelNum; iCnt++)
            {
                wRangeType = *(i_SlotInfo.wChRange + iCnt); //get range type
                EX_ScaleRawValue(wRangeType,
                                 wRawValue[iCnt],
                                 &dScaledValue,
                                 cUnit); //get scale value            
                if (strcmp(cUnit, "UN") != 0)
                {
                    printf("Channel %d raw data is 0x%04X, scaled value is %.4f %s.\n",
                           iCnt,
                           wRawValue[iCnt],
                           dScaledValue,
                           cUnit);
                    dest << dScaledValue << ",";

                    Sleep(1);
                }
                else
                    printf("Channel %d range is unknown.\n", iCnt);
            }
            dest << endl;
        }
        else
            printf("Fail to get value, error code = %d\n",
                   lGetMultiValueResult);
        dest.close();
        dest2.close();

        if (dest == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error creating file: ");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `char filename[20]`...`sprintf(filename, "%04d%02d%02d_%02dh%02dm%02ds.csv"`...I guess you like living on the edge of a buffer overflow occurring.  Looks like a buffer overflow to me.

Comment: objects defined inside a loop will be recreated on every iteration of the loop, so `dest` will be opened and closed for what looks like every reading. This may not be what you want. I recommend you stop coding for a while and put together a little logic diagram that describes the flow you want. Also check with your documentation to see when `timeinfo->tm_min < 60` is false.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Avoid buffer overflow is needed. But you can suggest me the way to handle the major issue as I mentioned first.

Comment: How do you know that the buffer overflow is not causing issues elsewhere?  You are overwriting the string, thus possibly clobbering other variables.

Comment: `<string>`, `<chrono>` and [`"data.h"`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) ftw.

Comment: @Swordfish: I don't get your point. I've already declared string.h.

Comment: Click the "data.h" link, Hector. You'll find Howard Hinnant has already solved a lot of your file-naming problems.

Comment: @HectorTa -- `<string.h>` is not `<string>`.  Second, the point being made by Swordfish that there are standard (and other) C++ alternatives to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I declared <chrono>, it showed error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'chrono.h': No such file or directory. I searched on the internet but haven't solved this problem.

Comment: @HectorTa Then either your compiler (which one?) doesn't support C++11 or you don't tell it to compile your code as C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard C++-facilities and Howard Hinnants [`date.h`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "date.h"

int main()
{
    auto now{ std::chrono::system_clock::now() };
    std::string filename{ date::format("%Y%m%e_%Hh%Mm%Ss.csv", now) };
    std::cout << filename << '\n';
}
```

I don't know what you're trying to do with the rest of your code, so ...

Comment: I'm using visual studio 10. Please tell me how to inform the VS compiler my code is as C++11

Comment: @HectorTa *visual studio 10* – Visual studio **2010**?

Comment: @HectorTa that it's totally outdated and its compiler won't understand anything newer than C++03? Is there a reason you can't upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 or 2019?